# Why only half of register bank is accessible in VFP's S0-31 view of register bank?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, neon

I am optimizing a simple l2-distance calculation program target at Cortex-A7. Initially, i choose to unroll the calculation loop like below:

```c
void l2_naive_f32(float *mat, uint32_t m, uint32_t n, float *vec, float *dst) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      float res0 = 0;
      float res1 = 0;
      for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j+=2) {
        float t0 = mat[i * n + j] - vec[j];
        float t1 = mat[i * n + j + 1] - vec[j + 1];
        
        t0 *= t0;
        t1 *= t1;

        res0 += t0;
        res1 += t1;
      }
      dst[i] = res0 + res1;
  }
}
```

I've observed that in the target Cortex-A7 CPU, unroll 8 times will reach the peak performance. Unrolling 16 times will cause massive register spilling https://godbolt.org/z/sdzovT73P.

In this [armv7-reference-manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Application-Level-Architecture/Application-Level-Programmers--Model/Advanced-SIMD-and-Floating-point-Extensions/Advanced-SIMD-and-Floating-point-Extension-registers?lang=en), i've learned that even though VFP register set contains thrity-two 64-bit doubleword registers, it can only view it as thirty-two 32-bit single word registers, S0-S31. Thus only half of the set is accessible in this view.

[image]

It's just a statement written in the manual that tells me about the truth. But my question is, what's the reason of this design? why only half of register bank is accessible in VFP's S0-31 view of register bank?

Comment: Not an answer, just a guess: v3 is backward compatible with v2 (which had 32sp/16dp registers) so the old opcodes would be valid also for VFPv4-D32 or VFPv3-D32 when accessing sp registers.

Comment: CPU instructions are not arbitrarily large, encoding a register takes bits, encoding *multiple* registers (1 for the instructions destination register, ~2 for the sources) takes a fair number of bits. If you double the number of accessible registers, you add a bit to every register specifier. Also, even with more user-adressable registers, you probably wouldn't improve performance by further unrolling, because an out of order processor can already rename registers to compute independent operations if there is no dependency.

Comment: ⬆ but using NEON (if you can) will surely help (possibly much more than manually unrolling the loop). `arm_neon.h` is there for you!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `aarch32` neon isn't IEEE754 compliant. The lack of subnormal number handling hurts especially.

Comment: The same with `aarch64` neon. There are 32 q registers, but you can only use 32 d registers. It is what it is. We have to live with it.  EOF's explanation is a really good one.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE yes, that _was_ often a problem in v7 but not _necessarily_ a problem for OP (@user8510613?)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That **is** a problem on **Cortex-A7** the OP shall be aware of.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE definitely! (_was_ = not anymore in v8)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti And the OP explicitly mentioned that he's targeting **Cortex-A7**.

Comment: @EOF IMHO it would have been (relatively) inexpensive to make them all available in two banks, without needing an extra bit (required only for this very specific case) but I agree with you: there is simply not (as far as I can imagine) a compelling use case (where 64 registers would benefit performance _enough_ to justify even this small investment in silicon; how much - with the proper compiler - you could gain, in general? Maybe 1 or 2%? just guessing now)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE yes, that's why I said "...if you can..." (AFAIK that is not always a problem)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE It's kinda annoying to provide access to partial registers on an out of order architecture.  X86 suffers from this problem and it makes sense for ARM to try and avoid this issue for ARMv8 by mapping scalar registers to vector registers in a 1:1 correspondence.  And really, what are you going to do with more than 32 registers anyway?

Comment: @fuz `aarch64` is considerably more "compiler friendly" compared to `aarch32`. Especially the neon permutation instructions such as `trn`, `zip`, and `uzp` are very well re-desdined on `aarch64`. And I agree with you on 32 registers being more than adequate. I just wish they get wider - to 256 and eventually to 512bit, like on `avx2` and `avx512`

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE You might enjoy SVE if you are into this sort of thing.  But OTOH, the Apple M1 matches Intel's AVX2 performance even though it has half the vector width.  So maybe vector width isn't the most important thing anyway.

Comment: @EOF Cortex-A7 is in order and can only partially dual issue.